# How to say if button is released in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, button, release

I am trying to make a game in which when a button is held down the block moves right, and when a different button is held it moves left.
How do I say when a button is released it should stop?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Outlets` tab of the inspector for the `UIButton`, connect `touchUpInside` and `touchUpOutside` to whatever method you want to run when the `UIButton` is released.

Comment: If you click the `UIButton` inside the `Interface Builder` you see the `Sent Events` inside the `Connection Inspector` on the right.

Comment: What does that mean? Connect it to the method? Like connect it to the button?

Answer (score 0):

I would do some reading on event listeners, and specifically in objective-c:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

If you design your event listener such that your 'block' moves ONLY when a button is held down, it should not be moving otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

UIButton can be set up to call a method (called an *action*) in response to a built-in event. There is a Touch Down event when the button is touched, and a Touch Up Inside or Touch Up Outside event when the button is released. So you'd want to set up appropriate methods for all of those, i.e. "start" for the Touch Down event and "stop" for the other two.

Comment: And see the documentation on action events: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events